# Closure under union of certain open covers

Tags: general-topology

Call an open cover $P$ "restrained" if each set $A$ in $P$ is a subset of a set $A'$ in $P$, where there is no set in $P$ that contains $A'$ as a proper subset. The idea is that each open set in a restrained open cover $P$ is contained in a "maximal" open set in $P$ which is not the proper subset of any open set in $P$. Such open covers are interesting, because taking the maximal elements of these open covers produces an open cover.

Is the union of two restrained open covers of a topological space $(X, \tau)$ also a restrained open cover of $(X, \tau)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be two restrained open covers of your topological space. Let $C_3$ be their union. Any element $U$ of $C_3$ that is also in $C_2$ is contained in a maximal element $M$ of $C_2$. If $M$ is not properly contained in any element of $C_1$, then $M$ is maximal in $C_3$ and so $U$ is contained in a maximal element of $C_3$. On the other hand, if $M$ is properly contained in an element $V$ of $C_1$, it is contained in a maximal element $M'$ of $C_1$. $M'$ is maximal in $C_3$ because it is not properly contained in any element of $C_1$ and if it were properly contained in an element of $C_2$, $M$ would be as well, contradicting the maximality of $M$ in $C_1$. So any element of $C_3$ that is contained in $C_2$ is contained in a maximal element of $C_3$. A similar argument shows that any element of $C_3$ that is also contained in $C_1$ is contained in maximal element of $C_3$. So $C_3$ is restrained.